# Visual Studio Code can not found Firefox even firefoxExecutable is setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code can not found Firefox, even firefoxExecutable is setting -  why?

```
{
  "name": "Mappings localhost",
  "type": "firefox",
  "request": "launch",
  "reAttach": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:4200/index.html",
  "pathMappings": [{
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
      "path": "${workspaceFolder}"
  }],
  "firefoxExecutable": "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox",
  "firefoxArgs": ["-start-debugger-server=6000"]
},
```

[image: VS code ignores Firefox]

Comment: You are missing `.exe`

Comment: unfortunately no, adding ".exe" can not help VS Code processing this config

Comment: Ups, I found. There is additional parameter override launch config - setting.json in foldes .vscode, this parameters has value "firefox.executable": "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" - and ".EXE" is must have

Comment: You should post and accept your own answer if you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found another setting, this setting always override value in launch.json. And of course, if you omit ".exe" suffix VS Code can not found Firefox

[image: another setting]